# Email Notification When Post Submitted

Tags: form, emails

Is it possible for a user group to be notified by email when a post is submitted using either the backend or a form on the front end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there isn't a native way to do this, but you could [write a plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) which would work like this:

- Wait for an [event](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events) like: [`content.onSaveContent`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#content-onSaveContent) or [`entries.onSaveEntry`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry)
- Get all users from a specific usergroup using the [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel).
- Use the [EmailService](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/emailservice) to send a mail to each of them.

.

**Quick-and-Dirty:**

```php
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    //Event: onSaveEntry
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {

        //Get all users from UserGroup
        $user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
        $user_criteria->groupId = '1';
        $users = $user_criteria->find();

        //Send to each User
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            //Send Mail
            $email = new EmailModel();
            $email->toEmail = $user->email;
            $email->subject = 'Heyyyyy';
            $email->body    = 'How you doin?';

            craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Victor, I am trying to get into simple plugin development so this is really useful. Is there are very simple boilerplate set of example files to learn how to add what you have given me and make it work as a plugin?

Comment: Except for the $user_criteria part, which I got from the 'G+ Dev Group' the rest of the code is copied out of the docs (see my links in the list above). Also 'reverse-engineering' other peoples plugins explains a lot (list: http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins ). Otherwise it's 'Try & Error' or asking ;)

Comment: Oh, and check out: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction which will help you get started. The `init()` functions goes into the main plugin-file.

Answer (score 6):

For those that are looking for a plugin that simply notifies users (*without* all the overhead), take a look at [Brief](https://github.com/taylordaughtry/brief). It's a **super-light** plugin that simply notifies users whenever a new entry is added to a Section.

If anybody has a specific need for it, I'd be glad to add features.

More information: [Brief](https://github.com/taylordaughtry/brief)

Comment: Nice work! You should submit it to [Straight Up Craft](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins), the official unofficial plugins listing.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could get in touch with Ben Parizek of Barrel Strength Design who has a plugin called [Sprout Email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email). Currently in beta but you can request a preview.

I am using it as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

Or, have a look at [Postmaster](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS), which works a treat!